# Swift IOS activeVideoMinFrameDuration not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I have a code to capture preview images from the app for image processing. I need to control the frame rate of the preview for that purpose, But the code to set the frame rate has no effect on the preview stream .Here is  the code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Starscream
import SwiftyJSON



class ViewController: UIViewController, WebSocketDelegate {
    
    
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    
    var rearCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var rearCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    var videoPreviewOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    var socket: WebSocket!
    let server = WebSocketServer()
    var isConnected = false
    var json:JSON = JSON()
    var json1:JSON = JSON()
    var jsonAction:JSON = JSON()
    
    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    
   
    var hr_raw1 = [Int]()
    
    var time_raw1 = [Int]()
    var bpm_list = [Double]()
    
    var time_list = [Int]()
    var frames1 = [Int]()
    
    
    var start_time:Int = -1
    var current_time:Int = 0
    var last_time:Int = 0
    
    var init_stamp:Int = -1
    var current_stamp:Int = 0
    var last_stamp:Int = 0
    
    @IBOutlet var bpmText: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var fpsText: UILabel!
    
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "wss://jznm58xz5i.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/production")!)
        request.timeoutInterval = 10
        socket = WebSocket(request: request)
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
        
        self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        
       self.captureSession?.sessionPreset = .inputPriority
        
        let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
        
        self.rearCamera = session.devices.first
        
        
        if let rearCamera = self.rearCamera {
            
            // we try to create the input from the found camera
            self.rearCameraInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearCamera)
            
            if let rearCameraInput = rearCameraInput {
                
                // always make sure the AVCaptureSession can accept the selected input
                if ((captureSession?.canAddInput(rearCameraInput)) != nil) {
                    
                    // add the input to the current session
                    captureSession?.addInput(rearCameraInput)
                }
            }
        }
        do{
            try rearCamera?.lockForConfiguration()
            try? rearCamera?.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
            rearCamera?.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
            rearCamera?.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
            rearCamera?.unlockForConfiguration()
        }catch{
            
            
        }
        
        if let captureSession = captureSession {
            // create the preview layer with the configuration you want
            self.videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            self.videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            self.videoPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
            
            // then add the layer to your current view
            view.layer.insertSublayer(self.videoPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
            self.videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.frame
        }
        
        self.videoPreviewOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        self.videoPreviewOutput!.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer"))
        
        // always make sure the AVCaptureSession can accept the selected output
        if ((captureSession?.canAddOutput(self.videoPreviewOutput!)) != nil) {
            
            // add the output to the current session
            captureSession?.addOutput(self.videoPreviewOutput!)
        }
        
        
        self.captureSession?.commitConfiguration()
      
        self.captureSession?.startRunning()
        
        
    }
```

the flashlight also turns off immediately as soon as the session starts, I can't understand why that happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check if it supports the desired FPS using this:

```
extension AVCaptureDevice {
    func configureFPS(_ inputFrameRate: Int) {

        var isFPSSupported = false

        do {

             let supportedFrameRange = activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges
                for range in supportedFrameRange {
                    if (range.maxFrameRate >= Double(inputFrameRate) && range.minFrameRate <= Double(inputFrameRate)) {
                        isFPSSupported = true
                        break
                    }
                }

            if isFPSSupported {
                try lockForConfiguration()
                activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(inputFrameRate))
                activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(inputFrameRate))
                unlockForConfiguration()
            }

        } catch {
            print("lockForConfiguration error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it does support but it is I am still not getting the set frame rate

Comment: Did you call this method on self.rearCamera and comment out your implementation for setting fps?